# Graphql query and Apollo

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I am using Apollo with React Native and I am doing a query to get the user data having his id, that is stored as prop.
This is the query:

```
const GET_USER_DATA = gql`
 query User($id: ID!) {
  User(id: $id) {
   id
   name
  }
 }`;
```

then this code

```
const User = ({ userId }) => {
console.log("User id: ", userId);
 return (
   <Query query={GET_USER_DATA} variables={{ userId }}>
     {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <Text>Loading ...</Text>;
      if (error) return <Text>Error!: {error}</Text>;
       return (
       <Text>Text: {data}</Text>
     );
    }}
  </Query>
 );
 }
```

and then, if the props exists I add this :

```
 <User userId={this.props.data.loggedInUser.id} />
```

To show the view.
But I get this error

```
Error: GraphQL error: Variable '$id' expected value of type 'ID!' but 
value is undefined. Reason: Expected non-null value, found null.
```

I am checking that the userId has a value and the value is printed, i can see it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the variable name from userId into id?

Something like:

```
const User = ({ id}) => {
console.log("User id: ", id);
 return (
   <Query query={GET_USER_DATA} variables={{ id }}>
     {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <Text>Loading ...</Text>;
      if (error) return <Text>Error!: {error}</Text>;
       return (
       <Text>Text: {data}</Text>
     );
    }}
  </Query>
 );
 }
```

and then:

```
<User id={this.props.data.loggedInUser.id} />
```

OR

assign the userId variable into the id param like:

```
const User = ({ userId }) => {
console.log("User id: ", userId);
 return (
   <Query query={GET_USER_DATA} variables={{ id: userId }}>
     {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <Text>Loading ...</Text>;
      if (error) return <Text>Error!: {error}</Text>;
       return (
       <Text>Text: {data}</Text>
     );
    }}
  </Query>
 );
 }
```